# Extra space at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, space

For some reason there is a ton of extra white space at the bottom of my page that I cannot seem to get rid of. I cannot put anything inside of the space nor can I get rid of it. I did some research and I have a hunch it has to do with the fact that my images are  `position:relative` but I'm still not entirely sure. If I need to get rid of `position:relative`, can somebody please tell me how else to place images that doesn't use `position:absolute` or `position:relative`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SDL.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<img src="img/SDL 4 Final Recompress.jpg" height="283" style="position: relative;"/>
<br/>
<hr width="500"/>


<img src="img/Studio-Light_sxu1.png"         style="position: relative; top: -496px; left:  30px; z-index: 3; height: 200px;"/>
<img src="img/Studio-Light_sxu1 flipped.png" style="position: relative; top: -496px; left: 650px; z-index: 3; height: 200px;"/>

<embed
src="http://blip.tv/play/AwGUv2w"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="669"
height="500" allowscriptaccess="always"
allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" style="position:relative; z-index: 2; top:100px; left:-200px">
</embed>

<img src="img/Stage-Background.png" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; height: 680px; top:-500px"/>
</center>

<div id="nav">
<p>All Episodes</p>
<a>Contact</a>
<a>Facebook</a>
<a>Meet the Crew</a>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me, no extra white space. Can you put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<img src="img/Stage-Background.png" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; height: 680px; top:-500px"/>
```

to

```
<img src="img/Stage-Background.png" style="z-index: 1; height: 680px; margin-top:-500px"/>
```

When you do position: relative, and move it, it keeps the rest of the document the same as if you had not moved it, so it has to keep the space below it.  If you do a negative margin top, it is pulling everything that the image moved down, up with it.

Comment: added explanation to the answer

Comment: awesome. Also, why does z-index still apply if you got rid of `position:relative`?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like

`<img src="img/Stage-Background.png" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; height: 680px; top:-500px"/>`

is causing your problem, try altering the

`height: 680px;`

see if the problem persists

Comment: Changing the height gets rid of the space, but it also shrinks the image. Is there another way I should alter it?